# Angular ui-grid sorting algorithm as service using Angular Factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I can't figure out how to pass an Angular Factory service into the sortingAlgorithm option in UI-Grid's options. Every time I do it gives me a console error of i is not a function. This is my factory:

```
.factory('sortFn', function(){
    return{
        sortAlphaNum: function (a, b) {
                var NUMBER_GROUPS = /(-?\d*\.?\d+)/g;

                var aa = String(a).split(NUMBER_GROUPS),
                    bb = String(b).split(NUMBER_GROUPS),
                    min = Math.min(aa.length, bb.length);

                for (var i = 0; i < min; i++) {
                    var x = parseFloat(aa[i]) || aa[i].toLowerCase(),
                        y = parseFloat(bb[i]) || bb[i].toLowerCase();
                    if (x < y) return -1;
                    else if (x > y) return 1;
                }

                return 0;
            }
    };
})
```

and

```
sortingAlgorithm: sortFn.sortAlphaNum(),
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use an anonymous function

```
sortingAlgorithm: function(a,b){return sortFN.sortAlphaNum(a,b)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`sortingAlgorithm: sortFn.sortAlphaNum()`

use this:

`sortingAlgorithm: sortFn.sortAlphaNum`